# Angular.js Rails Resource Association Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on an angular app w/ rails using [Angular Rails Resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource). When a user updates a photo, I want to query an association and update an attribute to `true`.

I have read through the Angular Rails Resource docs but I don't see much info on querying associations. Would this be an angular thing, or a rails thing?

Here is my angular code:

```
$scope.uploadHeadshot = ->
      Upload.upload(
        url: window.apiUrl + '/personas/' + $routeParams.unique_code + '/' + $routeParams.slug
        method: 'PUT'
        data: persona: headshot_attributes:
          image: $scope.headshot
          crop_x: $scope.cropAttributes.cropImageLeft
          crop_y: $scope.cropAttributes.cropImageTop
          crop_w: $scope.cropAttributes.cropImageWidth
          crop_h: $scope.cropAttributes.cropImageHeight
          # right here
          badge_attributes: completed: true).then ((response) ->
        $mdDialog.hide response.data
        resizeImage(false)
        return
      )
```

rails code

```
 def update
    @persona = Persona.friendly.find params[:id]
    @persona.assign_attributes persona_params
    return unprocessable_entity 'Invalid parameters', @persona.errors unless @persona.save
    render json: @persona, include: %w(modules owner badges)
 end
```

and in the `persona_params` I have the attrribute
`badge_attributes: [:id, :completed]`

I also have a attr on badge of `badge_type` so from the angular side I could get the current user, do a `badge.where(badge_type: 'badge type').update(completed: true)` but I'm not sure how to do that from angular. Or would this be a rails thing where you could do something like this from `#update`

```
if params[:badge_attributes]
  Badge.where(badge_type: 'badge type').first.update(completed: true)
end
```

What I have posted doesn't do anything, but it doesnt break the photo upload from happening, and I can see the `badge_attribute` params being sent. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this solved by doing the heavy lifting with rails.

```
if params[:badge_attributes]
  badge = Badge.where(persona_id: current_persona.id, badge_type: params[:badge_attributes][:badge_type]).first
  badge.update_attributes(completed: true)
end
```